# Incorrect Unicode Font Rendering in WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unicode

My setup is Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and developing a C#/WPF application in .NET 4.0.

In my application, I've a TextBox as follows:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxDescription" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS"
    FontSize="11" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    Width="300" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

From Character Map, I generated the following word:

[image: Character Map]

The way I generated the string is that I double clicked on 'ন', then double clicked on 'ি', followed by 'শ', 'া' and finally 'দ'. Notice that the final outcome is 'নিশাদ', which is correct in my language. I clicked Copy, and pasted in the TextBox mentioned above. The string is rendered as follows:

[image: WPF Window]

When I do the same in a C# Windows Forms application, the render is correct:

[image: Test Window]

Why WPF's rendering is different? How to resolve it?